# How to re-size image before uploading it to Firebase?

Tags: java, android, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I saw this question before but none of the solutions really suited my case.

I would like to save time uplading/downloading content from Firebase Storage in addition to save some space. Since firebase uses the image uri, I couldn't think of a proper way to achieve this.

A solution may be creating a "copy" to the cache or some temporary file to resize, crop, etc,then upload that copy to Storage. However I don't know if it is a good approach and I don't really know how to do it.

Would you suggest some ways of doing this? I really appreciate examples.

Comment: You can also use a Cloud Functions trigger to write the code that automatically performs the resize when the upload completes.  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail

Comment: @DougStevenson , I really like that approach but I never used Cloud Functions before, Is it a free or paid service? I will look more into it, thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could use some of the custom made `libraries` for compresing media files like images and videos. For example: **Compressor** is good library for compressing images: https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

To compress image and upload on `Firebase Storage` you could simply do something like this:

```
try {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                        .setMaxHeight(200) //Set height and width
                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                        .setQuality(100) // Set Quality
                        .compressToBitmap(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            final byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

And then when calling and setting `UploadTask`:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = StorageReference.putBytes(bytes);
```

Of course there are some other `libraries` like:

**SiliCompressor**

https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor

Comment: thanks for answering, I tried your code, but I'm getting this:  `FileNotFoundException: /primary:Pictures/night_sky_moon_trees_river_reflection_95979_1920x1080.jpg (No such file or directory)`  This is the file: `new File(data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri().getLastPathSegment());`   That is comming from an ImageChooser

Comment: That is something another `exception` which is raised when you try to read the file either file is not there or your reading is not correctly setup.

Comment: Yes I know what that the exception means, but how can the uri be wrong if it comes straight from the ImageChooser? Also that same uri worked in the above class. Thank you

Comment: `Log` the `Uri` if it's not `null` then there is probably there is no image with that `path`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a third party library, It's easy and efficient

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}
```

Compress Image File

```
compressedImageFile = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(actualImageFile);
```

Compress Image File to Bitmap

```
compressedImageBitmap = new Compressor(this).compressToBitmap(actualImageFile);
```

For more information visit this

https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

Hope this helps as I always use this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

Gradle

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.WindSekirun:MediaResizer:1.0.0' 
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
     maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
```

Compress Image

```
ImageResizeOption resizeOption = new ImageResizeOption.Builder()
            .setImageProcessMode(ImageMode.ResizeAndCompress)
            .setImageResolution(1280, 720)
            .setBitmapFilter(false)
            .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
            .setCompressQuality(75)
            .setScanRequest(ScanRequest.TRUE)
            .build();

ResizeOption option = new ResizeOption.Builder()
            .setMediaType(MediaType.IMAGE)
            .setImageResizeOption(resizeOption)
            .setTargetPath(path)
            .setOutputPath(imageFile.getAbsolutePath())
            .setCallback((code, output) -> {
                txtStatus.setText(ResultBuilder.displayImageResult(code, path, output));
                progress.dismiss();
            }).build();

MediaResizer.process(option);
```