# How do I reduce the size of a photo when uploading a photo to Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, bitmap, firebase-storage

I want to reduce the size of the photo when uploading photos to Firebase storage. There is an error in my codes. I wrote a method for sizing. Can you help? (kotlin)

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful && task.isComplete) {
            val userEmailInfo = auth.currentUser!!.email
            val currentUser = auth.currentUser
            currentUser.let { firebaseUser ->
                val storage = Firebase.storage
                val reference = storage.reference
                val userPicRef = reference.child(userEmailInfo!!).child("profilPicture")

                userPicRef.putFile(selectedPicture!!).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->

                    val uploadPicRef = storage.reference.child(userEmailInfo).child("profilPicture")
                    uploadPicRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                        val profilPicUrl = it.toString()
                        val userPic = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                        userPic["profilPic"] = profilPicUrl
                    }
                }
```

second.

```
private fun makeSmallerBitmap(image: Bitmap, maximumSize: Int): Bitmap {
    var width = image.width
    var height = image.height

    val bitmapRatio: Double = width.toDouble() / height.toDouble()
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maximumSize
        val scaledHeight = width / bitmapRatio
        height = scaledHeight.toInt()
    } else {
        height = maximumSize
        val scaledWidth = height * bitmapRatio
        width = scaledWidth.toInt()
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true)
```

}

Comment: I used firebase storage, it reduces its size quite a bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562587/how-to-re-size-image-before-uploading-it-to-firebase

Comment: There's an example library with code that generates a thumbnail copy of and uploaded image. See [Firebase Function Samples; Thumbnail](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/quickstarts/thumbnails). You can probably adopt that for your own use.